# TinyMCE Post Image Upload to Custom URL

Tags: php, upload, tinymce

In order to upload images to my server I need to post to a specific URL so that I can handle it on the back end. TinyMCE seems to provide support for such functionality, but it's not entirely clear or explicit about it.

I tried using JustBoil.Me to upload the image, but the way it's set up does not play nicely with my Laravel and URL setup.

Have any of you had to do this before?

I found this resource to be very helpful, but the lack of literature on this topic is shocking:

- [Direct Image Uploads in TinyMCE 4](https://pixabay.com/en/blog/posts/direct-image-uploads-in-tinymce-4-42/) (it would be amazing to see a PHP/Laravel server side code snippet on how to return something that TinyMCE can process)